# how to convert json object to a specified json format

Tags: javascript, json

how to convert

```
[{
    "10001": 30,
    "10002": 30,
    "10003": 50
}]
```

to

```
"fare": {
    "10001": {
        "10002": 30,
        "10003": 50
    },
    "10002": {
        "10001": 30,
        "10003": 30
    },
    "10003": {
        "10001": 50,
        "10002": 30
    }
}
```

using javascript

Comment: please reformat your question. It is unreadable.

Comment: `function convert(x) { return { "fare": {
    "10001": {
        "10002": 30,
        "10003": 50
    },
    "10002": {
        "10001": 30,
        "10003": 30
    },
    "10003": {
        "10001": 50,
        "10002": 30
    }
} } }`

Answer (score 0):

You should maybe learn more about algorithm and javascript to solve this problem as it is a specific example and not a general problem.

But this code do the trick :

```js
var json = [{
    "10001": 30,
    "10002": 30,
    "10003": 50
}];

var finalJson = {};
finalJson["fare"] = {};

Object.keys(json[0]).map(k1 => {
  finalJson["fare"][k1] = {};
  Object.keys(json[0]).filter(k2 => k1 !== k2).map(k2 => {
    finalJson["fare"][k1][k2] = json[0][k2];
  });
});

console.log(finalJson);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is better to understand the differences a bit more:

This is 1 `Array` with 3 `properties inside`

```
[{
    "10001": 30,
    "10002": 30,
    "10003": 50
}]
```

and this is 1 'Object with 3 `Properties that have an Object within`

```
"fare": {
    "10001": {
        "10002": 30,
        "10003": 50
    },
    "10002": {
        "10001": 30,
        "10003": 30
    },
    "10003": {
        "10001": 50,
        "10002": 30
    }
}
```

JSON could take any of the above, it just depends on what you will be doing with the data.

This link might help you understand more about JSON notation.  Hope this helps
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp